# Angular data binding within components not working when using jade

Tags: angularjs, express

I am using angular 1.6.4 and node 6.1 and I am trying to load a simple array that I have specified in the player-main component to the template but it does not get loaded correctly.

```
angular.
module('player').
component('playerMain', {
templateUrl: '/player.php',
controller: function PlayListController() {
    this.songs = [
        {
            id: 'one',
            title: 'Rain',
            artist: 'Drake',
            url: 'http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/rain.mp3'
        },
        {
            id: 'two',
            title: 'Walking',
            artist: 'Nicki Minaj',
            url: 'http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/walking.mp3'
        },
        {
            id: 'three',
            title: 'Barrlping with Carl (featureblend.com)',
            artist: 'Akon',
            url: 'http://www.freshly-ground.com/misc/music/carl-3-barlp.mp3'
        },
        {
            id: 'four',
            title: 'Angry cow sound?',
            artist: 'A Cow',
            url: 'http://www.freshly-ground.com/data/audio/binaural/Mak.mp3'
        },
        {
            id: 'five',
            title: 'Things that open, close and roll',
            artist: 'Someone',
            url: 'http://www.freshly-ground.com/data/audio/binaural/Things%20that%20open,%20close%20and%20roll.mp3'
        }
    ];

}
});
```

When the template url is called 'player.php' express router redirects it to following jade template.

```
 .container
.row
    .col-md-12
        h5 Songs
        ul
            li(ng-repeat='song in $ctrl.songs')
                button(music-player='play', add-song='song') {( song.title )}
                button(music-player='', add-song='song') +
        button(play-all='songs') Play all
        button(play-all='songs', data-play='false') Add all
hr
```

But even though ng-repeat does iterate over the array 5 times, the

```
{(song.title)}
```

does not get evaluated, it simply print it as a string.

Comment: Is this `{(song.title)}` the right syntax ? It should be double curly brace `{{song.title}}` .

Comment: How the hell did I miss that? Errrrr .......... Thanks a lot by the way, this was the case.